# What does "現代修真" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

> 現代修真

Is a type/category of novel, but what does it mean in English?

> 現代

Is basically modern, but what would

> 修真

mean in this case?

If 修真 means "Cultivating True Virtue", it doesn't seem to fit too well, so what would the English translation be?

Comment: 修真 means "cultivating immortality", and 現代 just suggests the background of the story is set in modern. Such novels are generally addictive but in fact no more than spirit narcotics.

Comment: Like that: 'spirit narcotics'! I don't think I will bother reading these books!

Answer (score 1):

百度 has lots of books under 现代修真小说完本, they seem to be about immortals.

修真 seems to be a Taoist phrase, '道教中，学道修行，求得真我，去伪存真为“修真”。' I think you're pretty close with 'cultivating the truth / the true reality / the true self'。

Answer (score 1):

修真, is a verb, means that make effort to become a 'god', this kind of novel god has many levels, people 修真 to level up. finally become a 'big boss'

different novel may has different god levels, maybe, “练气”，"筑基"，“金丹”，“元婴”.....

Recommended to read "凡人修仙传"

Answer (score 0):

- 修 = “cultivate" is okay in this word.
- 真 = "true, nature"

while these two words consisted in "修真” , that's means from self cultivated, to make oneself back the nature(true) connection with the world(nature) of human-being and the natural world should have. this kind of connection is before one will changed by the human-being environment, just like baby's connection with the world(赤子之心：baby's heart, naive but in admitting means), but “修真” made you got this on conscious, you got the ability or capacity to keep this kind of connection on conscious.

The final step of "修真" is "天人和一", which means "one devoted himself(herself) into natural world and combined himself into natural world"

Here are some different cognition about "natural world" in English language , "natural world" is the embody of the Dao（'道'）， Dao is some kind of thing you could talk about it's embody( the natural world), but human have no ability to define itself, and it's the essence of world( both human world and nonhuman natural world"). besides， here "修真” is the same as "修道“ in nearly all occasions。

Besides "true virtue" is seemed as parts of the true connection with true natural world.

Comment: Here are some difference cognition about "natural world" in English language ,